# I want to include a jar file in my build using maven

Tags: maven, pom.xml

The problem is like this

I have a maven build of my project already. But I have a requirement wherein I need to replace a .jar file located in WEB-INF/lib folder with another .jar file. This new jar file can be downloaded from a link.

What changes do I have to make in the pom.xml file to achieve this requirement. I tried to find out ways to do it but could not figure out the exact solution as I am a novice in Maven.

Comment: add that artifact as a dependency in pom file and may i know the jar you are trying to replace and motive behind the replacement ?

Comment: you just need to remove the dependency , install your dependancy.After this clean and install command will automatically remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the jar file is not found in any public maven repository you can install it in your local repository using the [install plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) `mvn install:install-file ...` and refer it as any other dependency